# cut the first field in a multiple fields file

Tags: unix

In the file below:

```
position1 456754 0/1:170,167:339:99:3370,0,3372:50:99:0.496 ./.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
position2 456759 0/1:161,162:325:99:3266,0,3215:50:99:0.502 ./.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
```

I want to get the output:

```
position1 456754 0/1 ./.
position2 456759 0/1 ./.
```

That is for the third and fourth fields, I want to get the first fields containing `/`

If there is only one column, I can do the following:

```
cut -d " " -f3 - | cut -f1 -d ":"
```

After pasting the first two column, this would give me only:

```
position1 456754 0/1
position2 456759 0/1
```

My file has around 200 columns, how can I extend this for all fields in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an awk one-liner that splits fields containing colons and replaces those whitespace-delimited fields with just one subfield. Something like this:

```
$ cat inp.txt
position1 456754 0/1:170,167:339:99:3370,0,3372:50:99:0.496 ./.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
position2 456759 0/1:161,162:325:99:3266,0,3215:50:99:0.502 ./.:.:.:.:.:.:.:.
$ awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if($i~/:/){split($i,a,":"); $i=a[1] } } } 1' inp.txt
position1 456754 0/1 ./.
position2 456759 0/1 ./.
```

The `for` loop walks through the list of fields. Then, if any field contains a colon, we `split()` the field into an array (`a`), and replace the entire field (`$i`) with just the first element (`a[1]`).  The `1` at the end of the command string is short-hand for "print this line", which will happen regardless of whether any substitutions were made.

If you want a simpler awk script at the expense of some CPU, this should also work:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { split($i,a,":"); $i=a[1] } } 1' inp.txt
```

This simply eliminates that `if()` condition, so that for every field on every line, you will replace that field with the "first colon-delimited subfield". For fields with no colon, this replaces the field with itself.

Alternately, for a less-robust solution, you could use `sed`:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/(:[^ ]*)( |$)/\2/g' inp.txt
position1 456754 0/1 ./.
position2 456759 0/1 ./.
```

This solution reads and substitutes strings within the line, rather than parsing fields the way awk was doing things. It probably would be exactly as reliable as an awk solution, though perhaps a little less flexible (for example awk would let you take a different subfield, whereas this sed solution would not).

Note the `g` at the end of the substitution command. That tells sed to execute this substitution "globally" rather than merely on the first match of the search regex.

This solution uses the `-r` option to tell sed to use extended regular expressions. If you're in OS X or some (older) flavours of BSD unix, use the `-E` option instead. In other unices, you might have to convert this to BRE.

Just two methods. I'm sure more will crop up in other answers.